# Правильный подход к парсингу

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, парсер

Здравствуйте, стоит следующая задача, спарсить email адреса пользователей соц сети Мой Мир, которые проявляли недавнюю активность.

Решение я вижу таким:

```
1) Собираем интересующие нас страницы
2) Открываем страницу
3) В html коде проверяем чтобы значение <span class="profile__user-status"> соответствовало требуемому, например там должно быть написано "онлайн, секунд/минут/часов назад или января/февраля"
4) Если 3 пункт выполняется, то из html кода забираем информацию вида "Страница пользователя xxx@mail.ru социальной сети Мой Мир."
5) Отделяем email адрес
```

Готово

Желаемое время парсинга хотя бы 1000 адресов за 1 мин. Лучше конечно больше.

С такой задачей сталкиваюсь впервые.
Вопрос, адекватно ли это реализовать на python? Или проще\быстрее сделать на другом ЯП (может js)? Если на другом, то на каком и почему?

Может уже есть частично готовые решения?

Если нет, то как в общих чертах можно решить мою задачу (какой подход использовать)?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: На python можно точно, но есть вероятность, что вас забанят за слишком большую активность.

Comment: Понял, тогда можно прикрутить прокси

Comment: @Kir, они и прокси забанят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, Питон будет лучшим вариантом. Есть хорошие библиотеки разбора HTML-страниц и целая система "умного скачивания" [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Скорость будет на 99% определяться возможностью запуска многих потоков, так чтобы Вас не забанили при этом. В использовании `scrapy` можно найти примеры, как можно это пытаться сделать.